# I mistakenly broke the fast an hour early due to my computer's clock; what should I do?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I am in college right now and there is no masjid near me so I break my fast according to prayer times. The other day, my computer was automatically  delayed by one Hour (because of the summer timing) and I thought it was time to break the fast while I still had to wait another hour, and didn't pay attention until I had already broken it. what should I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forgot I am fasting and realized after eat almost a meal](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/25926/forgot-i-am-fasting-and-realized-after-eat-almost-a-meal)

Comment: @azam It is not a duplicate because the OP did not *forget*.

Comment: But it can almost be mapped to the answer. @Erciyes

Comment: @azam I'm not sure what you mean by that...Did you take a look at the link I provided in my answer? Forgetting is different from eating accidentally. These are two different questions.

Answer (score 2):

Unintentionally breaking the fast does not invalidate the fast. You will get the full blessing of your fast Insha'Allah. Do not worry about it. Allah (SWT) has made Islam very easy for us.

Have a look at the following Hadith:

> [Al-Bukhaari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/30/40) (6669) and [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/13/222) (1155) narrated that Abu Hurayrah (may Allaah be pleased with him) said: The Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever forgets he is fasting and eats or drinks, let him complete his fast for it is Allaah Who has fed him and given him to drink.”

and this one:

> روى اِبْن خُزَيْمَةَ (1999) عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَة أن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قال
> مَنْ أَفْطَرَ فِي شَهْر رَمَضَان نَاسِيًا فَلَا قَضَاء عَلَيْهِ وَلا كَفَّارَة
> حسنه الألباني في صحيح ابن خزيمة   -
>
> [صحيح ابن خزيمة -  كتاب الصوم](http://library.islamweb.net/newlibrary/display_book.php?flag=1&bk_no=75&bookhad=1973)
>
> Ibn Khuzaymah (1999) narrated from Abu Hurayrah that the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him) said: “Whoever breaks his fast in Ramadaan by mistake does not have to make up that day or offer expiation.” Classed as hasan by al-Albaani in Saheeh Ibn Khuzaymah.

Source: [IslamQA](https://islamqa.info/en/50041)

Comment: One should add that the translation by islamQA in the second hadith; where it is translated to "by mistake", the arabic word for that is "نَاسِيًا" which likely mean "forgetfully" as in the first hadith (translated to forgets), using the same verb "نَسِيَ" . The same word "nasiyan" is used in this [hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/83/47) and translated to "forgetfully"

Comment: The hadith talks about forgetting not about mistakengly eating while remembering the fast. According to the hanafi madhab the former does not break the fast while the latter does. This hadith is specifically about forgetting.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between forgetting and eating accidentally.

If you ate because you **forgot** that you're fasting, then your fast will still be valid.

However, if you ate **accidentally** while remembering that you were fasting then your fast will be broken.

The following is from [seekershub.org](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2010/08/09/the-complete-guide-to-fasting/):

> For the second category, the principle returns to accidentally performing an act that vitiates the fast. It also includes acts performed by force of a third party. Accidentally means that one remembers that one is fasting but broke the fast by one’s own doing without the intention to purposely break the fast. [Tahtawi, Hashiyya al-Tahtawi; Related in Radd al-Muhtar] These actions are outlined below in the section ‘category 2.’
>
> If any of the actions from category 1 are performed forgetfully, then they do not vitiate the fast. Forgetfully means that one does not have the presence of mind that one is fasting when performing the action.

Based on this, I would guess that your fast was broken by accident (not by forgetting) and you would therefore have to make it up.